# How to reindex MySQL column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

assume MySQĹ table:

```
col_1    col_2    col_3
data_1x  data_2x  2
data_1x  data_2x  5
data_1x  data_2x  9
```

What is the easiest way to re-index col_3 to receive this...

```
col_1    col_2    col_3
data_1x  data_2x  1
data_1x  data_2x  2
data_1x  data_2x  3
```

The col_3 is a simple integer which is not primary or foreigner key. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I mean how to renumber them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:-

```
UPDATE TAB
SET col3 = (SELECT (@rownum := @rownum + 1) FROM (SELECT @rownum := 0) r)
```

I think this might help you.

Comment: Perfect, It is working as expected! Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Just for clarification: `SET` should be `col_3` instead `col1`, am I wrong? Anyway, I did the tests with `col_3` and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    col_1,
          col_2,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS col_3
FROM      table_name p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  col_1;
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working good for "SELECT", how can I make it permanent, by using "UPDATE"?

Answer (score 0):

best and fastest way:

```
alter table mytable drop column col_3;
alter table mytable add column col_3 int auto_increment primary key;
```

Comment: But if there's already a primary key? (Which I hope it is...)

Comment: No, it is not a primary key.